# Div boxes not positioning right

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here is the code for the 2 divs. It ends up with div.main stretching horizontally over the page and div.navigation positioning itself right under it on the left side. If I put float: top for div.navigation then the content stays in the same place underneath div.main but the box itself stretches over div.main.

```
div.navigation 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.main
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    margin-left: 194px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**UPDATE!!!
Here is the code and the outcome for the 2 divs in jsFiddle.**

http://jsfiddle.net/mqpkdefy/2/

Comment: Can you show us a jsFiddle? I dont see your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mqpkdefy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/mqpkdefy/22/)** . By default **div is block** level element which will take up entire browser width , if you haven't specified the any width to it..

```
div.navigation 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;    /*changes done*/
    padding: 5px;
}
div.main
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
     width:70%;   /*changes done  must provide the width to the main div */
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right:20px  /*changes done*/
}
```

If you want navigation to be on left hand side means, here is the Link **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/no448tsw/)** Just place the navigation div above the main div

Answer (score 0):

Hey  You just need to Remove the css property `Clear:left` from `div.main`

See it [working](http://codepen.io/undefinedtoken/pen/qxgjB)

Comment: div.navigation still is pushed below div.main borders. There are no other set parameters for div.main besides the CSS code which I posted. Maybe you would need some other code?

Answer (score 0):

Hey remove **clear:left** from Main div or set it as **clear:right;**

```
div.navigation 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.main
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: right;         /*changes done*/
    float: left;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    margin-left: 194px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: div.navigation still is pushed below div.main borders. There are no other set parameters for div.main besides the CSS code which I posted. Maybe you would need some other code?

Comment: Which dic should appear on the left ?  Navigation or content?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on Adarsh Gowda K R answer but I've just started here.

I have removed clear:left and changed float:left to float:right as I am assuming you want the main navigation menu on the left because of where it shows up in your original fiddle example.

The menu and main divs are wrapped in a div with class content which has a fixed width of 960px

As Adarsh Gowda K R suggested the main div ... has the display type of block which means it takes up the entire browser width.

```css
div.navigation 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}
div.main
{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: solid #079EA3 1px;
    width:788px;
}

div.content{
    width:960px;
}
```

See

http://jsfiddle.net/AuroraArcade/mqpkdefy/38/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Main Div's Width to some value.
By default it takes 100% of width..
Also remove margin-left as it is not required